# Java stream parallelStream: How to map multiple functions to stream map

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have this code that works on Arraylist. Each element in the array list need to be work by ArithmeticBBB and ArithmeticCCC and create 2 elements which be returned back to the stream.

I'm using `stream = stream.map(a::work)` in the loop, or using  flatMap.

```
class ArithmeticBBB implements ArithmeticManagerStream.ArithmeticAction {
        @Override
        public String arithmetic(String n) {
            String ss  = n+" 2" + " ,Thread ID:" +Thread.currentThread().getId();
            return ss;
        }
    }
    class ArithmeticCCC implements ArithmeticManagerStream.ArithmeticAction {
        @Override
        public String arithmetic(String n) {
            String ss  = n+" 3" + " ,Thread ID:" +Thread.currentThread().getId();
            return ss;
        }
    }
    
    public class ArithmeticManagerStream {
        private List<String> integerList = null;
        private List<String> resultArray = null;
    
    
        public ArithmeticManagerStream(List<String> dataFromUser) {
            this.integerList =  dataFromUser;
        }
    
        public List<String> invokerActions(List<ArithmeticAction> actions) throws
                InterruptedException {
    
            Stream<String> stream = integerList.parallelStream();
            for (final ArithmeticManagerStream.ArithmeticAction a : actions) {
                stream = stream.flatMap(str -> actions.stream().map(b -> b.arithmetic(str)));
             }
            return resultArray = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        public interface ArithmeticAction {
            String arithmetic(String n);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<ArithmeticAction> actions = new ArrayList();
            actions.add(new ArithmeticBBB());
            actions.add(new ArithmeticCCC());
            List<String> intData = new ArrayList<>();
            intData.add("1");
            intData.add("2");
            intData.add("3");
    
            ArithmeticManagerStream arithmeticManagerStream = new ArithmeticManagerStream(intData);
    
            try {
                List<String> result = arithmeticManagerStream.invokerActions(actions);
                System.out.println("***********************************************");
                for(String i : result) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, if you run this program you will see that the results are connected to the string.

```
1 2 ,Thread ID:12 2 ,Thread ID:12
1 2 ,Thread ID:12 3 ,Thread ID:12
1 3 ,Thread ID:12 2 ,Thread ID:12
1 3 ,Thread ID:12 3 ,Thread ID:12
2 2 ,Thread ID:1 2 ,Thread ID:1
2 2 ,Thread ID:1 3 ,Thread ID:1
2 3 ,Thread ID:1 2 ,Thread ID:1
2 3 ,Thread ID:1 3 ,Thread ID:1
3 2 ,Thread ID:13 2 ,Thread ID:13
3 2 ,Thread ID:13 3 ,Thread ID:13
3 3 ,Thread ID:13 2 ,Thread ID:13
3 3 ,Thread ID:13 3 ,Thread ID:13
```

What I need that each element will be in its own element e.g.:

```
1 2 ,Thread ID:12 
1 2 ,Thread ID:12  
1 3 ,Thread ID:12  
1 3 ,Thread ID:12 
2 2 ,Thread ID:1  
2 2 ,Thread ID:1 
2 3 ,Thread ID:1 
2 3 ,Thread ID:1 
3 2 ,Thread ID:13 
3 2 ,Thread ID:13  
3 3 ,Thread ID:13  
3 3 ,Thread ID:13
```

Comment: Are you trying to produce as many lists as there are `Iwork` objects in `w`? If not, what are you doing with the multiple *map* results? If you want multiple lists to result from applying those actions, you need multiple streams.

Comment: @ernest_k i updated the question with the end goal

Comment: Then all you need is `flatMap`. It's a bit like a Cartesian product.

Comment: @ernest_k can you give example ? thanks for the replay

Comment: Why are you doing `stream = stream.flatMap(str -> actions.stream().map(b -> b.arithmetic(str)));` in a loop? This almost certainly looks wrong. You're flatMap-ping on each action while iterating over actions. What are you trying to achieve? In other words, the loop should not be needed at all, and its body should be run just once.

Comment: the loop is for feed the actions with each element in the integerList , what better way i can do it ? as actions list may grow to 10 also

Comment: `stream.flatMap(str -> actions.stream()` is already iterating over actions for each string element. Why are you doing this in another loop iterating over actions?

Comment: I didn't know that this is what it doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the code in the posted question hasn't been stripped down from actual running code, due to the number of typos and other issues.  So it's impossible to tell what the actual problem was.

However, the following code does run:

```
public class ParallelStreams {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> strList = List.of("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5");
        List<IWork> w = List.of(new Work1(), new Work2());

        Stream<String> stream = strList.parallelStream();
        for (final IWork a : w) {
            stream = stream.map(a::work);
        }
        List<String> finalArray = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String s : finalArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}


interface IWork {
    String work(String s);
}

class Work1 implements IWork {
    @Override
    public String work(String s) {
        return s + " * " + Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
}

class Work2 implements IWork {
    @Override
    public String work(String s) {
        return s + " ! " + Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
}
```

and produces the following output:

```
a1 * 13 ! 13
a2 * 13 ! 13
a3 * 1 ! 1
a4 * 1 ! 1
a5 * 1 ! 1
```

In order to make it a little clearer as to which IWork implementation was running, I added either a " * ", or " ! " in place of the space in the original implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is what I did , except instead of doing LIst.of i added the IWork in a loop as im using java 8

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for changing this to runnable code so we can see what's going on.

You've made it a little harder to understand because the data is just single digits, while your actions are just single digits and the thread id's can be single digits.  So I've changed the data to "A", "B", and "C" to make it easier.

In your `for` loop, you're looping around `actions`, but don't actually use the `action` for anything in the loop.  So it's essentially just a loop that runs as many times as you have actions, but doesn't differ in each iteration.  You've made this more difficult to catch because you've called the loop variable `a`.  Try naming it something more meaningful.

What gets really confusing is that you're looping through `actions` and then streaming actions inside the loop.  So this squares the number of actions applied.  I can't believe that's what you're looking for, but you don't seem to be upset about that aspect of your output, just the fact that it's merged for each input.

Also, it's not clear how much you care about the threads themselves.  You have them in the output, but why?  Why use `ParallelStream()`?

You are also making it far more complicated by treating the Stream as a variable and moving it through steps.  In the first answer I posted, I found that combining it all together resulted in the entire stream running through a single Thread, so I didn't do that in that answer since I wasn't sure how important the threads were to you (and they shouldn't be).

In the end, it works perfectly if you dump the `for` loop, and then combine it all into a single Stream statement:

```
class ArithmeticBBB implements ArithmeticManagerStream.ArithmeticAction {
    @Override
    public String arithmetic(String n) {
        String ss = n + " 2" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return ss;
    }
}

class ArithmeticCCC implements ArithmeticManagerStream.ArithmeticAction {
    @Override
    public String arithmetic(String n) {
        String ss = n + " 3" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return ss;
    }
}

public class ArithmeticManagerStream {
    private List<String> integerList = null;
    private List<String> resultArray = null;


    public ArithmeticManagerStream(List<String> dataFromUser) {
        this.integerList = dataFromUser;
    }

    public List<String> invokerActions(List<ArithmeticAction> actions) throws InterruptedException {
        return integerList.parallelStream()
                          .flatMap(str -> actions.stream().map(action -> action.arithmetic(str)))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public interface ArithmeticAction {
        String arithmetic(String n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArithmeticAction> actions = new ArrayList();
        actions.add(new ArithmeticBBB());
        actions.add(new ArithmeticCCC());
        List<String> intData = new ArrayList<>();
        intData.add("A");
        intData.add("B");
        intData.add("C");

        ArithmeticManagerStream arithmeticManagerStream = new ArithmeticManagerStream(intData);

        try {
            List<String> result = arithmeticManagerStream.invokerActions(actions);
            System.out.println("***********************************************");
            for (String i : result) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
***********************************************
A 2 ,Thread ID:13
A 3 ,Thread ID:13
B 2 ,Thread ID:1
B 3 ,Thread ID:1
C 2 ,Thread ID:1
C 3 ,Thread ID:1
```

That seems about right to me.  Each source item passes through each of the actions, generating it's own output which is flatmapped back into the original stream.

A final note.  I was looking to streamline the code, and noticed that your interface is a `Functional` construct.  So you could actually ditch the implementation classes and just declare them with a lambda when you load up the `actions` array.  Then, of course, it became obvious that your interface is basically a `Function<String, String>`.  So I ditched the interface altogether and then cleaned up the code, using a Stream for the final output.

The result is essentially trivial, I added a bunch more actions just to make a point:

```
public class ArithmeticManagerStream {
    private List<String> integerList = null;

    public ArithmeticManagerStream(List<String> dataFromUser) {
        this.integerList = dataFromUser;
    }

    public List<String> invokerActions(List<Function<String, String>> actions) {
        return integerList.parallelStream().flatMap(str -> actions.stream().map(action -> action.apply(str))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Function<String, String>> actions = new ArrayList();
        actions.add(n -> n + " 2" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        actions.add(n -> n + " 3" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        actions.add(n -> n + " 4" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        actions.add(n -> n + " 5" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        actions.add(n -> n + " 6" + " ,Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        List<String> intData = new ArrayList<>();
        intData.add("A");
        intData.add("B");
        intData.add("C");

        ArithmeticManagerStream arithmeticManagerStream = new ArithmeticManagerStream(intData);
        List<String> result = arithmeticManagerStream.invokerActions(actions);
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
***********************************************
A 2 ,Thread ID:13
A 3 ,Thread ID:13
A 4 ,Thread ID:13
A 5 ,Thread ID:13
A 6 ,Thread ID:13
B 2 ,Thread ID:1
B 3 ,Thread ID:1
B 4 ,Thread ID:1
B 5 ,Thread ID:1
B 6 ,Thread ID:1
C 2 ,Thread ID:14
C 3 ,Thread ID:14
C 4 ,Thread ID:14
C 5 ,Thread ID:14
C 6 ,Thread ID:14
```